# How to whitelist recipients before mail goes to spamassassin?

Tags: linux, postfix-mta, spamassassin

I've been looking everywhere for a solution but didn't find.

What I need is to whitelist some recipient addresses so they won't ever go to the spamassassin filtering.

In my `master.cf` in postfix I have this:

```
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
    user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
    /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On your server, there is /etc/spamassassin/local.cf. You can add the address there.

Answer (score 2):

From https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.4.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html

> whitelist_to user@example.com
>
> If the given address appears as a recipient in the message headers (Resent-To, To, Cc, obvious envelope recipient, etc.) the mail will be whitelisted. Useful if you're deploying SpamAssassin system-wide, and don't want some users to have their mail filtered. Same format as whitelist_from.
>
> There are three levels of To-whitelisting, whitelist_to, more_spam_to and all_spam_to. Users in the first level may still get some spammish mails blocked, but users in all_spam_to should never get mail blocked.
>
> The headers checked for whitelist addresses are as follows: if Resent-To or Resent-Cc are set, use those; otherwise check all addresses taken from the following set of headers:
>
> ```
>     To
>     Cc
>     Apparently-To
>     Delivered-To
>     Envelope-Recipients
>     Apparently-Resent-To
>     X-Envelope-To
>     Envelope-To
>     X-Delivered-To
>     X-Original-To
>     X-Rcpt-To
>     X-Real-To
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Open this file:
`/etc/spamassassin/local.cf` and add this line:

```
whitelist_from abc@def.com
```

That will whitelist the address. To blacklist an address just use

```
blacklist_from abc@def.com
```

Also, I'm running Ubuntu, and they also include a file in the same location,
65_debian.cf. You can add that there as well.

Make sure this plugin is uncommented:

```
ifplugin Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::Shortcircuit

whitelist_from abc@def.com

...

endif
```

All your whitelist/blacklist rules along with custom scores and rules should fall within these lines.

Comment: I need to whitelist recipients, not senders. I tried whitelist_to and all_spam_to but it does not work for me.